# How does SQL*Plus connect to Oracle without a listener?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, listener

`sqlplus` can be used even if there is no listener in the system, or if it isn't running.

How does SQL*Plus connect to Oracle without a listener?

I can connect any user using SQL*plus even with no listener running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BalazsPapp mentioned, the oracle db can be connected locally even without a listener. In this case, the BEQ (Bequeath) protocol is used, instead of the tcp-based normal oracle communication.

Although on Balazs's [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e27508/netv2.htm#DFSIG380) there is nothing about the details of the BEQ. On unix, it probably uses unix domain sockets. On windows, it uses probably some local rpc.

Answer (score -2):

You only bypass the listener when you connect as sysdba*. Ordinary connections through SQLPlus still use the listener. As for how it does it, there is a special mechanism for this kind of connection, which allows a database to be administered without a working listener. I do not believe that the workings of this mechanism are published by Oracle. They want you to use the listener.

*Or as sysoper**. 
**And only if you don't specify a database in your connect string.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. Any user can connect locally without a listener, through the BEQ (Bequeath) protocol. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e27508/netv2.htm#DFSIG380